# Can't drop items with in a listview in my windows 8.1 app built using c#

Tags: c#, windows, windows-8.1, winrt-xaml

I have a windows 8.1 app with listview enabled drag, drop & reorder(all set to true), but when i try to drop the listview items with in listview to re-order i couldn't, **i am using visual studio express 2013 on windows 10**, i had uploaded my project here [Project](https://app.box.com/s/1htyrbnzwn8djue00ac84y1sxy9abaey) , my screen record is here [Video](https://app.box.com/s/72v38fnbtv9noj4rubixu9q3cqznmeid) , i tried a lot but couldn't find where the issue is, please help.

Comment: Show us what you tried until now, so we can help you...

Comment: i had uploaded my project to box, please download it from above.

Comment: it is very odd to see no one responding, please download my project from link given in my question description, it would be great if atleast someone say where i am going wrong.

Comment: @xoce better stay away from responding if you can't provide a suggestion.

Comment: Please read about [how to ask good questions](//stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and try to edit your question. With high quality questions you will receive better answers faster. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If the reordering features of the `gridview` are new to you, then you might benefit from reading this blog article explaining it.

> http://blog.jerrynixon.com/2013/06/walkthrough-reordering-items-in.html

The most common mistake developers make is not to use an ObservableCollection as the backend store for their items. You can't reorder a List or array.

Best of luck!